# Connection for micro USB connector

Tags: pcb, usb, connector, soldering, routing

I would like to solder micro USB connectors on my PCB, only for power (no data). I did that connection, but when I soldered it and connected the cable I could not have any power. Is my connection is ok? (the track coming from the right is the +5 V)

[image: PCB footprint]

The component I used is this one: https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/usb-connectors/7142353
I don't know if I should do something with the data pins, even if I'm not using them. And I don't know what's the purpose of "pins" 6 to 9.

The only thing I'm sure of is that the power is reaching the connector (I tested the potential between pin 5 and 1).

Thanks in advance for your help!
Please asked if I missed any crucial information.

Comment: Looks ok to me. How did you solder it? Pins 6 to 9 are the metal shield and also serve to give mechanical strength, they should be soldered to unconnected pads on the device side and connected to ground on the host side.

Comment: Probably something not well soldered, damaged during soldering, pin inside the connector damaged or damaged USB cable.

Comment: You might wanna connect the shield pads to larger "copper islands" though. If it's just the pads and they aren't connected to ground, you _will_ break this connector and have it leave the PCB with pads and everything. With larger copper areas you reduce the chance but it's still a bad design. The SMD variants of these connector families with no mechanical relief were simply designed by monkeys: mechanical relief is absolutely mandatory.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I soldered the connector "by hand", I don't have a machine/oven for that. I soldered on 3 PCBs and didn't work for all.
So you recommend I create fake pads connected to the ground for pins 6 to 9.
What is the difference with the SMD variant of this connector?

Comment: @DarkPatate Parts without mechanical relief will break whenever used in the real world. This has nothing to do with the electrical connection: the solder joints simply can't handle the force, nor can the PCB pads. I strongly recommend getting a part that grabs onto the PCB with mechanical relief though holes etc. Otherwise the whole crap part will eventually lift off from the board and likely take the PCB pads with it.

Comment: @DarkPatate the easiest method for a hobbyist without proper tools is actually reflow in a saucepan! It's quicker & neater than with a soldering iron. The only hard part is learning to apply the correct amount of solder paste by hand. The first time you'll be tempted to use about 5 times too much and you get solder bridges that need touching up. If you just use a pin prick of solder paste you don't even need to be very accurate for the positioning of the paste as it will snap to the pin when melted.

Comment: @Lundin, thanks for the comment. I didn't though about mechanical constraint! Hopefully, in my case, I'd not have to unplug it often. But it's better to do it.

Comment: @Damien, when you say "saucepan" it's a real saucepan for cooking or a specific tool?!

Comment: I mean a cooking pan -- anything with a flat bottom should work.